# Is numpy order dependent?

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point

I noticed that the output  of `numpy.mean()` and `numpy.var()` changes as the ordering of its arguments change.

It has to do only with the precision of floats, or I'm missing something?

```
import numpy

l1 = [1.0, 0.69, 0.65, 0.7, 0.64, 0.8]
l2 = [1.0, 0.7, 0.69, 0.65, 0.64, 0.8]

assert sorted(l1) == sorted(l2)

print repr(numpy.mean(l1))
print repr(numpy.mean(l2))

print repr(numpy.var(l1))
print repr(numpy.var(l2))
```

Here the output that I obtain:

```
0.7466666666666667
0.74666666666666659
0.015522222222222222
0.015522222222222224
```

Comment: Floating-point addition is commutative but not associative, so order of addition matters. For a more extreme example, try `l1 = [1e17, 3.0, -1e17]` and `l2 = [1e17, -1e17, 3.0]`, which have computed means of `0.0` and `1.0` respectively. (Incidentally, these two results will fail the `allclose` test that Mike Müller mentions.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NumPy uses (in this case) 64-bit floats. [Floating point numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) cannot represent all numbers with unlimited precision. 
This data type can hold 15 significant digits. This means the last digit in your number is meaningless.
Therefore, to compare our numbers use `numpy.allclose`:

```
>>> numpy.allclose(numpy.mean(l1), numpy.mean(l2))
True
```